# which is faster: bitshift vs switch

Tags: c, performance, networking

I am designing a multiplayer RTS tile based game where all game logic is handled by the server (written in C) and the client is being made in Unity for ease of cross platform deployment.

I am designing a custom protocol that will be sent over TCP my question is from an efficiency standpoint rather than a data size POV (the trade off), am I better off using bitwise operators to determine what action the user is trying to do or should I just be using a char(byte) and feed the int value into a switch statement? or is there another more efficient way I'm missing?

If I go the bitwise route it will be 2 bytes long and essentially be read as a bit array where the position of the '1' in the 2 bytes will determine what action will be taken and how the rest of the packet should be read.
eg

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned short); ++i)
{
  if((pkt & 1) > 0)
  {
    /* call correct function for bit at index 'i' with 
       remaining packet data (minus these 2 header bytes) */
  }
  pkt >> 1;
}
```

or should I just take the cleaner route of reading assuming a byte array or char* :

```
char val = pkt[0]
switch (val)
{
  case 65: 
      /* call relevant function */
         break;
  case 66: 
     /* call relevant function */
        break;
 }
```

**These examples assume I have already read the size of the data being received in the first 4 bytes**

Any insight as to which route I should be taking is much appreciated!

Comment: You should be building with optimizations enabled. And optimizers can do amazing things sometimes. The only way to say for sure is to build both versions and to profile.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok thanks I will run some tests, wasn't sure if there would be a clear cut answer or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jump table will probably be the quickest:

```
/* declaration of action functions */
int action1(char *data);
int action2(char *data);
int action3(char *data);
int action4(char *data);
int action5(char *data);
/* Filler */
int nop(char *data) { return 0; }

/* declare jumptable action as an array of function pointers of suitable type */
int (*action[])(char*) = { action1, action2, action3, action4, action5, nop, nop, nop };


/* Call function */
char val = pkt[0] & 0x07;  
result = (action[val])(pkt+2);
```

Comment: This looks like its going to work well for what I need. I will accept it as the answer.  If I do find a faster way to optimise I will come back and post what turned out to be fastest in my situation. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is also what an optimizing compiler will likely spit out from a switch statement, given that all indices are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

For the bitwise you could think a bit further:

```
    /* call correct function for bit at index 'i' ...*.
    switch (i) {
        case ...:
    }
```

...and so you have your switch again. Better leave optimizations to the compiler.

Comment: I was considering having an array of function pointers (yes I know its frowned upon) to remove the need for another switch but its still a look up I guess

Comment: @PSD- frowned upon by whom?

Comment: I was told at uni they are to be avoided due to type safety but in my instance for what im trying to do they seem to fit the situation

Comment: @PSD - Casting them should be avoided for type safety. But a table of function pointers, all with the same prototype, is quite idiomatic.